# Git for windows constantly corrupting

Tags: xcode, git, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm building an app using jQuery Mobile, PhoneGap, Exporting with Xcode and source control with GIT for windows.

I'm obviously doing something seriously wrong because after 5-10 commits the repository becomes corrupt and I can't use it any more, this is the 5th or 6th time, my app is getting pretty advanced, and I have NO RECORD whatsoever of the changes made over time.  In fact at this point source control for this app is a lost cause.

The commits are not extraordinary, in fact I could change a line or two and it will work splendidly, the next line or two: Failed to Commit!

Is anyone having this issue, have you figured out why?

Actually trying a commit yields:

> commit failed - Failed to create a new commit

git fsck yields:

> Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
>  broken link
>   from   tree 'long alphanumeric'
>                 to   tree 'long alphanumeric'
>  dangling blob 'long alphanumeric'
>  dangling tree 'long alphanumeric'
>  dangling blob
>   'long alphanumeric'
>  dangling blob 'long alphanumeric'
>  dangling
>   blob 'long alphanumeric'
>  dangling blob 'long alphanumeric'
>   missing tree 'long alphanumeric'

I have restarted my repo about a dozen times and this will happen half-way through the day every time...

Comment: I would test a) the network connectivity, b) remote repo storage media and c) local repo storage media health.

Comment: you will get far better response if you provide exact error messages. without them this is not a real question

Answer (score 1):

- You **have to** test your repository with `git fsck`,
- You *can* clone repo in some another location and try to work with clone
- You *can* change Git-client (maybe it will help, but I doubt it)
- You *can* send Git to trash and use another SCM

Answer (score 0):

Use GitExtensions - way better and functional!